# Is there a simple way to plot polynomial rational function?

Tags: polynomials

For example, is there a simple way to plot this function:
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^3-16x}{-4x^2+4x+24}
$$
rather than calculate the value for each point and connect each point to plot the graph?

Comment: One way is to compute the zeros of the function, the denominator, the derivatives, their zeros, etc. The (sign of the , and the zeros of)derivative will tell you if/where $f(x)$ is increasing/decreasing; similar for (the sign of, the zeros of) $f'(x)$

Comment: Thank you! However, although I know how to do derivative, but this question comes from pre-calculus class and my friend didn't learn about derivative yet...So is there another simple way?

Comment: @shingdai: let me think for a bit.

Comment: How accurate does your plot need to be?

Comment: @JackM: Just like graph drawn by hands and it should seems like (I mean shape) it's accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all linear factors, no repeats (nothing squared) ..

EDIT: got some values off a calculator, this should be a bit closer to horizontal near the origin, otherwise the drawing is fine. Makes sense, without using calculus, the location and type of asymptotes is clear and the linear growth at infinity is clear, positive or negative or zero is clear, but the relative size between a root and an asymptote was a complete guess.

[image]